# Entendendo as informações do meu perfil

Tags: suporte

Não sei se é aqui que devo perguntar. Mas, eu vejo onde deveria ter o meu avatar, que tem o meu nick e 133 uma bolinha alaranjada e o número 4. O que significa isso?

Comment: `133` é a sua reputação e o número `4` é o de medalhas de bronze, vc pode ver todas nesse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Agora só tem uma bolinha alaranjada pq migraram sua pergunta para o `meta stackoverflow pt` e aqui a contagem das medalhas é feita em separado do site principal. Já sua reputação é contabilizada apenas lá e refletida aqui (as vezes com um pouco de atraso)

Answer (score 13):

Representa a sua identidade na rede. Você tem um perfil público aqui: [**pnet**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6420/pnet).

Lá você pode ver diversas estatísticas sobre a sua conta, além de [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/6420) algumas informações pessoais, como a sua foto.

O número que aparece acompanhando seu nome em todo o lugar é a sua reputação. Você ganha reputação por coisas que faz no site, como perguntar, responder.

- <kbd>+10</kbd> por voto positivo em uma resposta
- <kbd>+5</kbd> por voto positivo em uma pergunta
- <kbd>+15</kbd> por ter uma resposta aceita
- <kbd>+2</kbd> por aceitar uma resposta
- <kbd>+2</kbd> por ter uma sugestão de edição aceita
- <kbd>-1</kbd> por votar negativamente em uma resposta
- <kbd>-2</kbd> por receber um voto negativo

Você pode ganhar reputação como recompensa também. Vale notar que aqui no meta ninguém ganha reputação, apenas medalhas. A reputação aqui é um espelho da do site. Para mais detalhes: [**O que é reputação?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Com reputação você adquire [**privilégios**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) que te permitem fazer mais no site.

As bolinhas acompanhadas por números são medalhas que você ganha por acontecimentos especiais na comunidade. No seu perfil você pode [ver a lista de medalhas que você tem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6420/pnet?tab=badges). E na central de ajuda há a lista de todas as medalhas, acompanhadas de uma descrição: [**Medalhas**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Answer (score 6):

O número corresponde à **reputação** que você ganha perguntando, respondendo e editando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja [O que é reputação? Como se ganha (e se perde)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

---

E as "bolinhas" correspondem às **medalhas** que você ganha por determinadas atividades e participação no site:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Veja a lista completa das medalhas que você pode ganhar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Não sei se com outros é igual, mas tenho esse defeito. Vou a um forum e já começo a responder, sem saber como funciona. Fim de semana próximo, vou entrar no stack e ler tudo que eu puder ler para entender como funciona. Ele é bem diferente dos demais foruns que conheço.

Comment: @pnet, a primeira diferença é que **não é um fórum** ;) As regras são fáceis porém estritas, o que garante a qualidade pela qual o site é conhecido.

Answer (score 3):

Ali indica seu perfil no site, suas reputação e suas medalhas que são adquiridas através da reputação.

Você pode conhecer bem mais a respeito disso, por fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help), lá você terá uma visão macro do site e aprenderá muitas coisas de como funciona o StackOverflow.

(Ps: fica a dica, fazer o Tour te garante mais uma medalha ;))